# generic foreach iteration of NamedNodeMap

Tags: java, xml, iteration, generics, w3c

In Java, looking at the [NamedNodeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NamedNodeMap.html) interface, how do you iterate it with generics?  It seems to use Node rather than String, but I'm not so sure how to use Node objects...

```
NamedNodeMap namedNodeMap = doc.getAttributes();
Map<String, String> stringMap = (Map<String, String>) namedNodeMap;
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : stringMap.entrySet()) {
  //key,value stuff here
}
```

Yes, I can see how to iterate without using generics and with a regular for loop, but I'd like to use the above ?idiom? for maps.  Of course, the problem would appear to be that, despite the name, NamedNodeMap doesn't actually implement the Map interface!  :(

Guess you just gotta bite the bullet here and do something like:

```
/*
 * Iterates through the node attribute map, else we need to specify specific 
 * attribute values to pull and they could be of an unknown type
 */
private void iterate(NamedNodeMap attributesList) {
    for (int j = 0; j < attributesList.getLength(); j++) {
        System.out.println("Attribute: "
                + attributesList.item(j).getNodeName() + " = "
                + attributesList.item(j).getNodeValue());
    }
}
```

there's nothing nicer?

Comment: Isn't that quite nice? I mean it is a loop over each attribute node!

Comment: Those non-standard names should be forbidden in important libraries.
Should be called NamedNodeList and nobody would get confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a nicer way to use those APIs.  (Update: OK - maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/28626556/139985 counts as nice.)

Bear in mind that the W3C DOM Java APIs were specified before Java had generics or the new `for` syntax, or even the `Iterator` interface.  Also bear in mind that the W3C DOM APIs for Java are actually the result of mapping an IDL specification to Java.

If you want nicer APIs for manipulating XML, etc in memory, maybe you should look at JDOM.

Answer (score 9):

You can create your own `Iterable` wrapper for `NamedNodeMap` and then use it in a *foreach* loop.

For example, this could be a simple implementation:

```
public final class NamedNodeMapIterable implements Iterable<Node> {

    private final NamedNodeMap namedNodeMap;

    private NamedNodeMapIterable(NamedNodeMap namedNodeMap) {
        this.namedNodeMap = namedNodeMap;
    }

    public static NamedNodeMapIterable of(NamedNodeMap namedNodeMap) {
        return new NamedNodeMapIterable(namedNodeMap);
    }

    private class NamedNodeMapIterator implements Iterator<Node> {

        private int nextIndex = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (namedNodeMap.getLength() > nextIndex);
        }
        @Override
        public Node next() {
            Node item = namedNodeMap.item(nextIndex);
            nextIndex = nextIndex + 1;
            return item;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Node> iterator() {
        return new NamedNodeMapIterator();
    }
}
```

In this case, this would be the usage:

```
private void iterate(NamedNodeMap attributesList) {
    for (Node node : NamedNodeMapIterable.of(attributesList)) {
        System.out.println("Attribute: "
                + node.getNodeName() + " = " + node.getNodeValue());
    }
}
```

With a similar approach you could create an `Iterable` over `Map.Entry<String, String>` instances.

Comment: This (and its sibling `NodeListIterable`) is an absolute life saver when you have to work with DOM.

Answer (score 4):

As you can't cast [NamedNodeMap](https://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/NamedNodeMap.html) to a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), I suggest to loop using a classic for loop like that :

```
int numAttrs = namedNodeMap.getLength();
System.out.println("Attributes:");
for (int i = 0; i < numAttrs; i++){
   Attr attr = (Attr) pParameterNode.getAttributes().item(i);
   String attrName = attr.getNodeName();
   String attrValue = attr.getNodeValue();
   System.out.println("\t[" + attrName + "]=" + attrValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Java 8 solution:

```
private static Iterable<Node> iterableNamedNodeMap(final NamedNodeMap namedNodeMap) {
    return () -> new Iterator<Node>() {

        private int index = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return index < namedNodeMap.getLength();
        }

        @Override
        public Node next() {
            if (!hasNext())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            return namedNodeMap.item(index++);
        }
    };
}
```